# How to change the indent length for blocks in algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e

Algorithm2e automatically indents the code within a block, e.g. inside if-then-else.

How can one change the size of this indent?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation. There is `\SetAlgoHangIndent{length}` but it only applies to lines automatically broken because they are too long.

Comment: Can you add a MWE ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the indentation with `\SetInd`. From the documentation:

> `\SetInd{before rule space}{after rule space}` sets the size of the space before the vertical rule and after. In `\NoLine` mode the indentation space is the sum of these two values, by default 0.5em and 1em

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \If{cond}{do\_something}
    \SetInd{0.1em}{2em}
    \If{cond}{do\_something}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]